# PHP Sessions on multiple sites

Tags: php, session

I have multiple sites hosted on a server and most of them use sessions when users login.

for example, i have a session variable `$_SESSION["loggedin"] = 'yes'` if the users login is successful.

this is the same on multiple sites but if i login to say 2 sites at the same time one of them will stop working and  display these errors:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_8f7b4997fbfdd08855a410ae4638821f, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/theboaty/public_html/new_site/admin/authorisation.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/theboaty/public_html/new_site/admin/authorisation.php:2) in /home/theboaty/public_html/new_site/admin/authorisation.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/theboaty/public_html/new_site/admin/authorisation.php:2) in /home/theboaty/public_html/new_site/admin/authorisation.php on line 5

Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_8f7b4997fbfdd08855a410ae4638821f, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

Note: `authorisation.php` checks for the `loggedin` session variable to see if the user is logged in or not

Comment: Are you sharing (or purpose or inadvertently) the same session ID between sites?

Comment: The code is just copied when new sites are added. Not done on purpose

Comment: If you are using Firefox, cookie manager can be reached by right-clicking on page and selecting "View page info-> Security-> Cookies".

Comment: im not setting cookies though ?

Comment: Your session is setting a cookie.

Comment: Perhaps when you say "multiple sites hosted on a server", do you mean "multiple sites hosted on a domain"?

Comment: oh right okay - but why do i want to go to the cookie manager, i am unable to do this on the visiter/guest computers. whats the best way to stop this from happening all together?

Comment: nope multiple sites hosted on a server. i have 1 server with cPanel and WHM installed on it so lets say 3 websites/domains - this will be 3 accounts

Comment: Are all sites on subdomains eg site1.domain.com site2.domain.com etc or totally different domains domain.com and another.com

Comment: Through the cookie manager you may see which session id's are alive.  It looks like "authorisation.php" tries to use the same session for all the sites.

Answer (score 0):

I have much the same problem because I use a custom user handler that takes sessions.

I found that logging onto two different related sites on the same server using the same browser window but with different tabs there was crosstalk.

If this is not acceptable, I suggest you rename your session variables by site vis:

```
$_SESSION['site1']['isloggedin']=1;
```